# How can I add single-character items to a list in design-time?

Tags: vb6, design-time

I've got a VB6 form with a ComboBox on it, which I'm trying to add a few single-character items to (specifically, 'A' through 'D'.) I can enter them into the properties box (using `Ctrl-Enter` to add new lines) and I get a box that looks like this:

[image: Listbox with single-character items.]

When I accept the list items, however (by hitting `Enter` or moving focus,) it replaces all my single character items with squares:

[image]

This happens to all single-character items, but not any multi-character items I may add. The items are actually changed (it's not just a display issue), and show up as boxes when actually running the program as well. Obviously I can add the items programatically, but I'd rather do it during design-time for simple applications like this one. Is this a bug in the VB6 IDE, and is there a workaround?

Comment: Odd, I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

i see .Disable all add-ins close vb and enter again test and after enable add-ins. in my case that fix it

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a non-standard (or unicode) regional setting on your machine do you - try using English (United Kingdom) for both regional setting and keyboard setting and see if this helps.

When I wrote a VB6 app that used Arabic some time ago I had to change locale and reboot my box every time I wanted to edit the arabic strings in the resource file as it would screw up otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue many years ago, but not any more.
I think the fix was to install VB6 service pack 6.